# iOS double navigation bar by set translucent OFF

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

at First:
I work with the storyboard interface builder...

I tried to color my navigation bar like Instagram:

```
UIColor *mainColorBlue = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.071 green:0.337 blue:0.533 alpha:1];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:mainColorBlue];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:mainColorBlue];
```

But if i set the color to mainColorBlue, it is not this color. I've read in the internet, that it is cause from translucent. So I set translucent to OFF.

But now, my Problem is: If i deactivate the translucent and activate opaque and start the app on my external device, under the navigation bar is another navigation bar. If i switch the translucent to ON again,the second navigation bar isn't shown.
What i have to do, that the second navigation bar disappear?

Comment: where did u put this code ?

Comment: But the setting from translucent i change in my storyboard-file

Comment: can u add screenshot of it ?

Comment: You mean from my storyboard?

Comment: screenshot of the issue!!!!

Comment: i can't upload images cause my reputation...

Comment: upload on imgur and paste the link here

Comment: http://imgur.com/TOdHe0S

Comment: do u have any other navigation bar added somewhere in the code ?  Because that really looks like there are 2 nav bars!!!  I tried your way, even with translucent ON/OFF nothing changed the nav bar appearance!!!

Comment: Not in the storyboard: http://imgur.com/xJwxoq3        I will look in the ViewController-File

Comment: I solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the problem.

I added a subview on position 0,0 to color the statusbar.

```
UIView *statusBarColor = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
statusBarColor.backgroundColor = mainColorBlue;
[self.view addSubview:statusBarColor];
```

So this View is displayed under the navigation bar. I removed this code and now it works.